# Scraping table from website into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape the table on the right of this website: https://www.tennisabstract.com/current/2022WTAAngers125.html

I have tried to use the XML path:

```
"//*[@id='forecast']"
```

But it returns an error, is there something I am missing?

When I try to scrape other items from the site, i.e. using:

```
"//*[@id='pmF']"
```

I have no issues, and the formula returns the expected value of 'F'.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the table on the left of this website:`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected values? And, your expected URL is only `https://www.tennisabstract.com/current/2022WTAAngers125.html`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I meant to say on the right, I would like to scrape the table with the header "**Singles Forecast**". The table includes a list of names and then percentages against those names.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your expected values. When I saw the HTML data of your URL, it seems that the table is created by Javascript. In this case, IMPORTXML cannot be used. But, I think that Google Apps Script can be used for this situation. In your goal, to use Google Apps Script is included in your expected goal? By the way, your expected URL is only `https://www.tennisabstract.com/current/2022WTAAngers125.html`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike yes that is the expected URL. As long as Google Apps Script is free and can export the data straight into a Google Sheet, than happy to use it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample Google Apps Script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw the HTML data of your URL, it seems that the table is created by Javascript. In this case, unfortunately, I thought that IMPORTXML cannot be used. But, I think that Google Apps Script might be able to be used for this situation. So, in this answer, I would like to propose achieving your goal using Google Apps Script.

From your following reply,

> that is the expected URL. As long as Google Apps Script is free and can export the data straight into a Google Sheet, than happy to use it.

I understood that using Google Apps Script is included in your expected goal. And, your URL is `https://www.tennisabstract.com/current/2022WTAAngers125.html`.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and please set your sheet name you want to put the values to `Sheet1` of `const sheetName = "Sheet1";`. And save the script.

And, before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

And, please run the function `myFunction` with the script editor. By this, a dialog for authorizing the scopes is opened. Please permit it. By this, the script is run.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://www.tennisabstract.com/current/2022WTAAngers125.html"; // This is from your question.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const r = res.getContentText().match(/var projCurrent = '([\w\s\S]*?)'/);
  if (r) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); // Please set your sheet name.
    const requests = [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: r[1].trim(), coordinate: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId() } } }];
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the URL of `https://www.tennisabstract.com/current/2022WTAAngers125.html` and put into the sheet "Sheet1".

#### Note:

- **This sample script is for your provided URL of `https://www.tennisabstract.com/current/2022WTAAngers125.html`. If you change the URL and the structure of the HTML data is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.**

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)